# Why is the volume percentage set with amixer not shown correctly in the UI?

Tags: audio

I'm trying to adjust the volume with amixer: `amixer sset 'PCM' 99%`.

The command is executed correctly but when I have a look on the Raspbian control volume indicator, I could see on the popup: 96%.

I would like to have the same level of the volume with amixer than viewed in the Raspbian control volume indicator. Which file I need to modify to obtain this?